# Executing Scala objects in Eclipse without a main method

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin

I have an assignment to code several methods in Scala. The methods will be encapsulated in an object that has no main method. The professor gave us a JAR file that contains an interface (my object implements this interface) as well as a sort of pseudo test object that performs various assert statements against each of my functions. This object also does not contain a main method.

Now in Intellij I simply had to declare the dependency on the JAR in the classpath, and it runs fine. Eclipse is giving me trouble though because when I go to define a Scala application run configuration it specifically asks me to name the class that contains a main method, and there is no main method.

I am assuming that I might be choosing the wrong project type for this type of set up, but I am inexperienced with this and I would appreciate any advice you might have for running something like this in eclipse.

Thanks.

Comment: the jar probably contains unit tests, so you need to choose, run as -> JUnit test  or similar

Comment: Just assert statements from Scala.Predef, no JUnit tests

Comment: In that case, the jar file must contain a class with a main method? You can just select that as the main object in the "Run Configuration" panel.

Comment: No the test object in the jar file does not contain a main method. Even though there is no main method I was still able to run it in Intellij, and I am just wondering if there is a way to do the same in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would either:

1. just write an object with a main method which calls the test object, or
2. start a Scala interpreter in your project (from context menu, under Scala).

Preferring the first approach, because it's faster to repeat tests after a modification.

Comment: He gave us the structure for our file, and there are specific comments not to change how the test object is called. The call is the last line in the file, and it's outside of the object where the methods are defined. I am assuming that if he intended for us to have a main method it would be in the file, but I see your point.

Comment: Ah, so it's intended to run as Scala script (with `scala ???.scala` command). You could add `scala` as an external tool (see http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~leavens/ComS541Fall05/meeting-outlines/scala.txt).

Comment: I took a look at this and was indeed able to achieve the kind of functionality I was looking for using an external tools config. You get the win! Thanks so much for your time.